# dsget the users in a group, or member groups

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

I am using the chain of commands to get a report of the members of group AD_GROUP_NAME.

> dsquery group domainroot -name AD_GROUP_NAME | dsget group -members | dsget user -display -email

And it works great, unless the group has a group as a member. Then I get an error `The object class of the target does not match the one specified on the command line.`

Is there a command I could pipe the result of the `dsget group - members` that will filter out the group objects from the returned results passing only users to `dsget user`? Or even better, is there a way to recursively walk the results so I can get everyone who is in the group via inheritance?

Comment: I'd rephrase the question as 'How can I generate a report of recursive group members displaying the member and their email address in the output? Here's what I've tried so far...' This way you'll get a lot more useful feedback with multiple solutions. Personally, I'd use the PowerShell Get-ADGroupMember cmdlet to accomplish this task, but offering that as a solution wouldn't answer your question.